# How to make NSNotificationCenter only run when a certain UITextField is selected

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter

I am using `NSNotificationCenter` to shift the main view frame up when a keyboard is shown.

However, I only want this to work for when one `UITextField` is selected.

Here is what I have so far:

```
func getKeyboardHeight(notification: NSNotification) -> CGFloat {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo

    let keyboardSize = userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue

    return keyboardSize.CGRectValue().height

}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.view.frame.origin.y -= getKeyboardHeight(notification)
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.view.frame.origin.y += getKeyboardHeight(notification)
}

func subscribeToKeyboardNotifications() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
}

func unsubscribeToKeyboardNotifications() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
}

func subscribeToKeyboardHide() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

func unsubscribeToKeyboardHide() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}
```

> In ViewWillAppear()

```
self.subscribeToKeyboardNotifications()
self.subscribeToKeyboardHide()
```

> In ViewWillDisappear()

```
self.unsubscribeToKeyboardNotifications()
self.unsubscribeToKeyboardHide()
```

How do I make the view shift up when I am only selecting one specific `UITextField`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
if yourTextfield.isEditing{}
```

Or this

```
if yourTextfield.isFirstResponder{}
```

To check is this is your textfield

Answer (score 1):

You can create the following extension

```
 extension UIView {
    /**
    Finds the first responder

    :returns: the first responder, or nil if nothing found.
    */
    private func findFirstResponder() -> UIView? {
        if isFirstResponder() { return self }
        else {
            for view in subviews as! [UIView] {
                if let responder = view.findFirstResponder() {
                    return responder
                }
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it like this in your `keyboardWillShow`

```
let textField = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.findFirstResponder() as? UITextField
```

You can now use textField currently active.